# MFMailComposeViewController display positioning

Tags: ios, email

When I call Apple's MFMailComposeViewController class to send an email from my app, the placement of the To, Cc, Bcc and Subject is a little off. They appear about 1/2 the font size down further than they are supposed to be (when you click the edit the subject, for example, you can only see the top half of the text). This happens even when I copy and paste Apple's sample right into my code. Has anyone seen this before? I've been searching through forums and can't see anybody else who has experienced this.

Code I'm using

```
MFMailComposeViewController *picker = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
picker.mailComposeDelegate = self;

[picker setSubject:@"Hello from California!"];

// Set up recipients
NSArray *toRecipients = [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"first@example.com"]; 
NSArray *ccRecipients = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"second@example.com", @"third@example.com", nil]; 
NSArray *bccRecipients = [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"fourth@example.com"]; 

[picker setToRecipients:toRecipients];
[picker setCcRecipients:ccRecipients];  
[picker setBccRecipients:bccRecipients];

// Fill out the email body text
NSString *emailBody = @"It is raining in sunny California!";
[picker setMessageBody:emailBody isHTML:NO];

[self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code:

```
    MFMailComposeViewController *picker = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    picker.mailComposeDelegate = self;
    NSString * subj = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"" ];
    [picker setSubject:subj];


    // Set up recipients
    NSArray *toRecipients = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"first@example.com",nil];
        NSArray *ccRecipients = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects::@"second@example.com",@"third@example.com", nil]; 
NSArray *bccRecipients = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects::@"fourth@example.com"]; 


    [picker setToRecipients:toRecipients];
        [picker setCcRecipients:ccRecipients];  
        [picker setBccRecipients:bccRecipients]
    [toRecipients release];
        [ccRecipients release];
        [bccRecipients release];

    NSString *body = @"";

    [picker setMessageBody:body isHTML:NO]; 
    [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
        [picker release];
```